# Mathjax vs Katex

Tags: math, mathjax, katex, mathquill

I would like to write a small web application to host a bunch of math questions for my students. It appears that MathJax and Katex  are two of the most popular libraries for doing this.

I have read a few articles comparing the two, but they are mostly a couple years old and it seems both have come quite a long way since then.

Can anyone write an up-to-date comparison of the two, and which might be better for typing up highschool math problems to include in a web application?

I am interested in (a) ease of use (ie learning curve) (b) browser and mobile compatibility (c) compatibility with front-end frameworks such as React, Angular and Vue, and backend frameworks (Django, Node JS, RoR)

Comment: For a), ease of use, the one which your friends/colleagues are using is best (because if they can explain it is easy to use), for b), compatibility, the one is best which supports your browser and mobile, for c) the one which supports most of the intended target market. This is either the answer or the reason why this is an opinion-based question, using "opinion" as "environment-specific". Otherwise, asking for a up-to-date comparison as an answer here is feeling very off-topic, if anybody writes something like that they want to publish elsewhere.  I am using the opinionation to reflect that.

Comment: Habe you looked at those "couple years old" comparisons? Which aspects there would be relevant to your decision? Have you checked whether those are still accurate? By own knowledge is a couple of years old, but the synchronous operation of KaTeX vs. the asynchronous one of MathJax were most relevant to me, and I'd assume that still holds these days.